# Styling Twitter Bootstrap search form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a search form using Bootstrap. Here's the HTML:

```
<form class="form-search search-bar">
  <div class="input-append">
    <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Enter your address here...">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    Search <i class="icon-search icon-white"></i></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'm new to CSS - how do I style this so that the search elements are horizontally centered across the block? Also, how do I increase the height of the search elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an ID

```
.search-bar {
    text-align: center; /* centers inline and inline-block children */
}
.search-bar .search-query,
.search-bar .btn-primary {
    display: inline-block; /* allows for heights to be set */
}
.search-bar .search-query {
    height: 30px;
}
.search-bar .btn-primary {
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that text-align centers the search form on the page. Any ideas?

Comment: Ahh figured it out. You need to set text-align: center one level above to .search-bar instead of at .input-append. Must be due to styling set on "input-append" since it's a Bootstrap class. Can you edit the answer so I can accept? 
Thanks, I assumed text-align would only deal with the alignment of text so I didn't use it.

Comment: yeah, it works if you put it on any parent. edited. `text-align: center` works on anything `inline` or `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

to place them next to eachother you can use the float command

```
.search-query {
  float:left;
}
.btn-primary {
  float:left;
}
```

Make sure the width of `input-append` is large enough to place them next to eachother.

to increase there `height` just place height:[amount]; in the same block as `float` in the CSS

Comment: they are already inline... floating does nothing. You might as well make them `display: inline-block`